# NTRU Pseudo-code for computing Polynomial Inverses

Tags: pseudocode, polynomial-math, inverse, ntruencrypt

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to implement line 45 of the following pseudo-code.

```
Require: the polynomial to invert a(x), N, and q.
1: k = 0
2: b = 1
3: c = 0
4: f = a
5: g = 0 {Steps 5-7 set g(x) = x^N - 1.}
6: g[0] = -1
7: g[N] = 1
8: loop
9:  while f[0] = 0 do
10:         for i = 1 to N do
11:             f[i - 1] = f[i] {f(x) = f(x)/x}
12:             c[N + 1 - i] = c[N - i] {c(x) = c(x) * x}
13:         end for
14:         f[N] = 0
15:         c[0] = 0
16:         k = k + 1
17:     end while
18:     if deg(f) = 0 then
19:         goto Step 32
20:     end if
21:     if deg(f) < deg(g) then
22:         temp = f {Exchange f and g}
23:         f = g
24:         g = temp
25:         temp = b {Exchange b and c}
26:         b = c
27:         c = temp
28:     end if
29:     f = f XOR g
30:     b = b XOR c
31: end loop
32: j = 0
33: k = k mod N
34: for i = N - 1 downto 0 do
35:     j = i - k
36:     if j < 0 then
37:         j = j + N
38:     end if
39:     Fq[j] = b[i]
40: end for
41: v = 2
42: while v < q do
43:     v = v * 2
44:     StarMultiply(a; Fq; temp;N; v)
45:     temp = 2 - temp mod v
46:     StarMultiply(Fq; temp; Fq;N; v)
47: end while
48: for i = N - 1 downto 0 do
49:     if Fq[i] < 0 then
50:         Fq[i] = Fq[i] + q
51:     end if
52: end for
53: {Inverse Poly Fq returns the inverse polynomial, Fq, through the argument list.}
```

The function `StarMultiply` returns a polynomial (array) stored in the variable `temp`. Basically temp is a polynomial (I'm representing it as an array) and v is an integer (say 4 or 8), so what exactly does `temp = 2-temp mod v` equate to in normal language? How should i implement that line in my code. Can someone give me an example.

The above algorithm is for computing Inverse polynomials for NTRUEncrypt key generation.
The pseudo-code can be found on page 28 of [this document](http://www.wpi.edu/Pubs/ETD/Available/etd-0430102-111906/unrestricted/corourke.pdf).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to implement NTRUEncrypt also and since you've done this and considering your method of storing the coefficients is quite similar to mine, I'd really appreciate it if you can give me a hand with the inverse function. Any chance I can contact you by email?

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try my best to implement this for now. I downloaded the document you posted and am going through with it. Might have to bother you in the next few days.

Comment: I sent you an email. Just wanna know if you've received it in case I got the address wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each entry in temp, temp[i], set temp[i] = 2-temp[i] mod v.

This should correspond to the "Inverse in Z_p^n" section of my response to [Algorithm for computing the inverse of a polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421409/algorithm-for-computing-the-inverse-of-a-polynomial/2426520#2426520).

As I look at it now, I think my answer may not do what it says -- it says "Inverse in Z_p^n" but it looks more like an inverse in Z_2^n. So it should work for p=2 but maybe not for anything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot william, just another quick question, in: 2-temp[i] mod v, the modulo applies to 2-temp[i] rather than just temp[i], correct?
So I should compute (2-temp[i])%2 rather than 2-(temp[i]%2) right?

Comment: hey william, I'm trying to find the inverse of a(X) mod 32, after running the first 31 lines of the algorithm for the polynomial a(X)=[-1,1,1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,1,-1] my program returns: b(X)=[1,1,0,0,0,1] and c(X)=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1] and k=11; I already know from the NTRU tutorial that the inverse of a(X) mod 32 is [5,9,6,16,4,15,16,22,20,18,30] however when I continue with the rest of the code i get a different answer. I was wondering if you could check whether my value for b(X) that I get after the first 31 lines is correct? If you could do that I would be extremely grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Neville -- my implementation of the inversion algorithm doesn't map exactly onto your pseudocode so it might take me a couple of days to work this out. Hope this is okay.

Comment: Hi william, thanks, I finally managed to implement the pseudocode successfully, however I had a small question. To be able to generate polynomial with inverses for key generation, the NTRU tutorial advises to use a polynomial f=1+p*F, where p=(2+x), and F is a small polynomial, now in the tutrorial with an N=11, it is advised to choose F in such a way that it has dF coefficients equal to 1 and the rest equal to 0, for N=11, dF=4 was used, I was wondering what the relation between N and dF was, say for a polynomial of N=251, what value for dF do I need to use? Thanks in advance.