# NTRUEncrypt inverse of polynomial algorithm

Tags: java, cryptography, polynomial-math, inverse, ntruencrypt

Well I'm trying to implement NTRUEncrypt and I found this [Algorithm for computing the inverse of a polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421409/algorithm-for-computing-the-inverse-of-a-polynomial) and this [NTRU Pseudo-code for computing Polynomial Inverses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461019/ntru-pseudo-code-for-computing-polynomial-inverses) but since I don't usually work with pseudo-code, I can't seem to understand it.

Can someone help me by explaining what are the variables and what type of data they are? Preferably the algorithm from the first question.

It'd probably be better if I can contact the posters but I have no idea how to do that since they didn't leave any email in their profile.

Comment: You can contact the posters by adding a comment to their answer.

Comment: At the time I asked the question, I didn't have enough reputation to do that. I do now and I've managed to contact them.

Comment: OnBoard Security has a very nice 4-part tutorial at [NTRU Resources](https://www.onboardsecurity.com/products/ntru-crypto/ntru-resources). You should visit the site and take some time to read the tutorials. You might also find [NTRUOpenSourceProject | GitHub](https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto) useful. If you look around you will find points of contact.